# Protecting Java webapp (using JAX-RS) against too big HTTP requests

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs

I have a JAX-RS 1.1 resource `FooBar` that has a method which accepts a `String` POST parameter as follows

```
@Path("/foobar")
public class FooBar {

  @POST
  public void doSomething(@FormParam("name") String name) {
    //...
  }
}
```

Is it possible to protect this from being called if `name` is longer than a specified maximum? I wonder what it does if the name is of size 1GB?

Comment: Clarify the goal: In my web client I give a maxlength 255 to the HTML input field. I'd like to have this constraint on the server side as well (POST might come from malicious client) without writing explicit length checks in the doSomething method if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, you can configure maximum size of post request on ServletContainer. For example, Tomcat has `maxPostSize` setting in httpConnector directive. By default it's 2 mb or so in Tomcat.

Comment: This is a more overarching solution that may actually be better, given there's nothing in the application that would expect something over a maximum post size. If there is something, however, like a file upload, where up to 2GB may be appropriate, but on ```doSomething()``` it is not, this would be overly constraining.

Answer (score 1):

Typically you would use a filter. Here's [an example in Grails](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/ref/Plug-ins/filters.html), [and one in Ruby](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters). Here's a tutorial that would show how to do this in [Jersey](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/821-0540/ug_restbc-filters_p/index.html).

Comment: adding such a filter is a bad idea, since servlet container have to refuse it on lower level. Not on application lvl

Comment: It's hard to say if the Servlet container should, based upon the information in the question.